# 'wrong host & port for passive connection' error while uploading files on FTP using sftp.jar

Tags: java, ftp

I am getting following error while uploading files on FTP.

```
com.jscape.filetransfer.FileTransferException: wrong host & port for passive connection                
    at com.jscape.filetransfer.FtpTransfer.upload(Unknown Source)
    at Aaaa_gb.m(FtpUtil.java:145)
    at com.cs.probe.Uploader.run(Uploader.java:206)
```

I am creating a single FTP connection and using this connection.
It works for sometime and then starts to give above error.
When new connection is created, it works again for some time before giving the same error.

I am using `sftp.jar` for FTP upload in java.

Comment: could you please post some code of your connection?

Comment: Why don't you ask for support on JScape? You are using a commercial product.